# Cannot add attributes to validation message

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a class to the validation messages added by my HtmlHelper:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(
    m => m.Status, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "validation-summary" })
```

But I am getting this error:

> CS1739: The best overload for 'ValidationMessageFor' does not have a parameter named 'htmlAttributes'

But according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721293(v=vs.118).aspx) this is the correct parameter name.  I don't want to pass in a custom message.

Comment: Can you just pass null for the custom message arg? `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Status,null,new {})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a a couple of [ValidationMessageFor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and none of them is matching your code. The overload you want to use is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721293%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and can be called like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    string validationMessage,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

so you need to add one parameter more:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(
    m => m.Status, 
    null,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "validation-summary" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct overload, you're skipping the `string validationMessage` parameter.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(
    m => m.Status,
    null,
    new { @class = "validation-summary" })
```

Note I'm substituting the validation message with a null, you could of course place a `string` here if you'd like.